# nextLine() Issues with java Scanner Class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class b {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] lines = new String[5];

        lines[0] = keyboard.nextLine();
        lines[1] = keyboard.nextLine();
        lines[2] = keyboard.nextLine();
        lines[3] = keyboard.nextLine();
        lines[4] = keyboard.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the above code not allow me to store the following:

```
Hello there
How are you
My name is
Bill Gates
What is yours?
```

The output I get is:

```
Hello there
How are you
My name is

Process completed.
```

I know there are issues with primitives and nextInt() but I thought nextLine() was supposed to address this.

Comment: Can show use whole code please?

Comment: The above code works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this, I get this:

```
Hello there
How are you
My name is
Bill Gates
What is yours?
```

as expected.

Check that you are not running an old version of your program. Also test your application from the command line to rule out any `IDE` issues with formatting.

Comment: I get:  
Hello there  
How are you  
My name is

Comment: With spaces between each line

Comment: I have tried running this on another machine and I got the same results. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @OmarQayum The block of code you are showing is perfect and no problems at all. However how are you executing your code. I meam through command line or through any IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: The snippet above runs just fine. Is there anything else in your code or the way the data is input to cause the spaces?

Comment: @OmarQayum Problem could be that you need to delete previously generated `.class` files. Then compile and run your program one more time.

Comment: I have updated my post. That is all I am using. No matter what the input, I get spaces